# How to get function line from backtrace?

Tags: android

I got the backtrace like this:
D callstack-test: #00 pc 000001c5  /system_ext/app/MyService/MyService.apk (offset 0x59c9000)

This code is in jni code by my testing which is built as libjni.so and I expect the backtrace is like below
D callstack-test: #00 pc 0004f049  /system_ext/app/MyService/MyService.apk!libjni.so (offset 0x59e8000)
But per the result,it is only have apk name and donot have library name, so I can use addr2line to get the function line.

Per google's document,"Frames #00–#03 are from native JNI code that was stored uncompressed in the APK to save disk space rather than being extracted into a separate .so file." See it in https://source.android.com/docs/core/tests/debug.

My question is that if backtrace is based on apk name, how can I get function line for the code in jni?
Thanks in advance.

David

If backtrace is based on apk name as below, how can I get function line for the code in jni?
D callstack-test: #00 pc 000001c5  /system_ext/app/MyService/MyService.apk (offset 0x59c9000)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using for years google-breakpad, and not only for android, but for windows and linux as well:
https://github.com/google/breakpad

To display stack traces in web-browser i use nodejs reports collecting server (at the moment of crash its showing backtrace of all native threads, including crashed):
https://github.com/acrisci/simple-breakpad-server

Builing android project with jni library, its producing both unstripped (with symbols) and stripped (no symbols) .so libraries.
Unstripped is located here:
your_project/app/build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/release/out/lib/armeabi-v7a/your_lib.so
Building the project each time i upload unstripped .so to the simple-breakpad server.

On loading your .so , you should setup google_breakpad::ExceptionHandler with the pointer of function, which will be called at moment of crash.
And the minidump you need to send by google_breakpad::HTTPUpload in this callback function.

To deploy all this is taking some time, but finally effort pay out, because you can use this crash reporting for all your projects, for debug and production.

I'm not sure if i answered your question, i just described the way i'm fighting crashes.

Comment: Thanks for your information. I managed to get the function line from objdump and its pc value which is based on knowing the jni lib name.
Now the question is that according to offset 0x59c9000,can I get the library name?

Comment: i think this might help you:
https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/ndk-stack
and if you look sources of it:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/master/ndk-stack.py
exactly rewrite From:   GoogleCamera.apk ... To: GoogleCamera.apk!libsomething.so ...